# How / Can I do this in CSS?

Tags: css, gradient

Take a look at this banner:

http://schart.net/newbanas.png

Can I make this stripish pattern using CSS? I want this to change whatever width the container is, so it should be CSS.

I'm making a portfolio and I want to sort out sections with this style of background.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a few good cheat sheets on the web to do with CSS3 shapes. Try searching for that.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question: yes, yes you can.

Comment: Yes you can. Here's a generator for it too: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ If you actually want to learn how to do it, Lea Verou has a good article here:http://lea.verou.me/2010/12/checkered-stripes-other-background-patterns-with-css3-gradients/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the concept quite a lot, so I basically duplicated it:

[image]

The CSS is somewhat complicated, but I basically used the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to create triangles:

```
body {
    background: #EEEEEE;
}

.stripe {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 72px;

    height: 130px;
    line-height: 130px;

    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s all;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.red {
    color: white;
    background: #CD3333;
    border-color: #CD3333;
}

.red:hover {
    background: #d24747;
    border-color: #d24747;
}

.blue {
    color: white;
    background: #6495CA;
    border-color: #6495CA;
}

.blue:hover {
    background: #77a2d0;
    border-color: #77a2d0;
}

.stripe:after, .stripe:not(:first-child):before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position:absolute;

    top: 0;
    right: -50px;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 130px 50px;
    border-color: transparent inherit;
}

.stripe:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 45px;
}

.stripe:first-child {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.stripe:not(:first-child):before {
    left: -50px;
    right: auto;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Nq35k/19/**

It only works in WebKit browsers. It should work with Firefox, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.

The easiest/quickest way can be using a generator like http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor

For instance, here's a fiddle for a sample created using this generator: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/VYRe2/

[image: screenshot]

*This is fairly cross-browser as well!*

**HTML**

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->

<div class="stripey gradient">TEST GRADIENT</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.stripey{
    background: #ff7577; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #ff7577 0%, #ff7577 34%, #207cca 34%, #2989d8 34%, #2989d8 69%, #7db9e8 69%, #eaecff 69%, #eaecff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff7577), color-stop(34%,#ff7577), color-stop(34%,#207cca), color-stop(34%,#2989d8), color-stop(69%,#2989d8), color-stop(69%,#7db9e8), color-stop(69%,#eaecff), color-stop(100%,#eaecff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #ff7577 0%,#ff7577 34%,#207cca 34%,#2989d8 34%,#2989d8 69%,#7db9e8 69%,#eaecff 69%,#eaecff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #ff7577 0%,#ff7577 34%,#207cca 34%,#2989d8 34%,#2989d8 69%,#7db9e8 69%,#eaecff 69%,#eaecff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #ff7577 0%,#ff7577 34%,#207cca 34%,#2989d8 34%,#2989d8 69%,#7db9e8 69%,#eaecff 69%,#eaecff 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #ff7577 0%,#ff7577 34%,#207cca 34%,#2989d8 34%,#2989d8 69%,#7db9e8 69%,#eaecff 69%,#eaecff 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff7577', endColorstr='#eaecff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

Another way to do it is using precisely positioned `div`s with slanted borders. This comes with it's own set of boons and banes, so which one you pick depends pretty much on the purpose! The slanted-edged block element method is presented in a good tutorial here: http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles

If you actually want to learn about the magic behind it, Lea Verou has a good article on her blog: http://lea.verou.me/2010/12/checkered-stripes-other-background-patterns-with-css3-gradients/